# Como não sobrepor rotulos(annotations) no google charts?

Tags: google-charts, gráfico

Estou desenvolvendo um gráfico de linhas, onde os rótulos(annotations) são fixos, porem alguns pontos ficam muito perto uns dos outros, assim sobrepondo um rótulo no outro.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de mudar a posição dos rótulos de maneira dinâmica ou estática(posicionando em locais diferentes)?

Lembrando que gostaria de deixá-los sempre fixos, ou seja, sempre aparecendo, sem a necessidade de colocar o mouse em cima dos pontos para que apareça as informações.

Segue um exemplo de como está:
[image: Gráfico Exemplo - Rótulos sobrepondo os outros]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usa o stem... eu estava com a mesma dificuldade... defina o item 1 positivo e o item 2 negativo, desta forma o annotation 1 ficará a cima do eixo, e o 2 abaixo...

```
series: {
              0: { annotations: { stem: { color: "transparent", length: 5}, alwaysOutside: true, textStyle: { color:'red',  bold: true, fontSize: 30 } } },
              1: { annotations: { stem: { color: "transparent", length: -40},  alwaysOutside: true, textStyle: { color:'yellow', bold: true, fontSize: 30 } } },
            }                
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Nas `options`, dentro de `annotations`, do seu gráfico acrescente `alwaysOutside: true`. Deixará as anotações do lado de fora.

```
annotations: {
     textStyle: {
         color: 'black',
         fontSize: 11,
     },
     alwaysOutside: true
}
```

Nessa parte da [Documentação](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart), fala sobre `annotations`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém não é isso que eu quero. Posso ter me expressado mal. Quero que uma annotation não sobreponha a outra. Isso que você indicou é para q a annotation fique fora das colunas. Olhe o que a documentação fala: annotations.alwaysOutside

In Bar and Column charts, if set to true, draws all annotations outside of the Bar/Column.

Type: boolean

Default: false

Comment: @AmarildoMartins, acho que não tem como resolver esse bug com as funções do google charts. Você vai ter que sobrescrever o SVG ou fazer com CSS.